# Can Ionic Spark proc more than once with area on-hit attacks?

Tags: league-of-legends

I specifically refer to Twitch's **Spray and Pray**, and Shyvana's **Twin Bite** while in Dragon Form. These both apply on-hit effects to *everything* caught in them, which had already been a source of monstrous hilarity with Tiamat.

Now that Ionic Spark has been brought to Summoner's Rift, I've been pondering its usage, and it made me curious. Unlike the Storm Shield buff in Dominion, Ionic Spark doesn't have an explicit 4 second cooldown, as it is limited to just auto-attacks. Does this mean that, if I use an attack that hits at least 8 times (a lot easier with a double-hitting Twin Fang, as it were), would two or more chain lightning effects proc simultaneously?

It doesn't feel *quite* as practical as Tiamat in terms of focusing on the splash on-hit, since the targets of the chain lightning are going to be random when you hit a large enough cluster to take major advantage of the splash. Nevertheless, I'm still curious.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From what I have done and seen, and from what I have read, it does indeed proc multple times when striking multiple enemies with AoE attacks that proc on-hit effects.  So Shyvana's **Twin Bite** in her dragon form would instantly proc twice if you strike four targets with it, four times if you manage to hit eight.  Same with **Spray and Pray**.

(P.S. The chain lightning effect also appears to cause spellvamp.)

Comment: Shouldn't Twin Bite proc twice when hitting 4 targets, on account of it hitting twice per target?

Comment: @Grace Note It probably does.  When I was playing as Shyvana I wasn't 100% sure if it was proccing, so I didn't mention that here.